# GridView OldValue and NewValue Best Practices

Tags: gridview

I got to work but is this the best way?
On changing a value in a GridView using a SQLDataSrc i need to see if it changed from N to Y and if it did, do something. I would like input if I did it in the most efficient way.

```
OnRowUpdating="GridView_RowUpdating"

    protected void GridView_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    String OldValue = e.OldValues[0].ToString();
    String NewValue = e.NewValues[0].ToString();

    if (OldValue == "N")
    {

        if (NewValue == "Y")
        {
            //do something
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Only problem I found is if the condition is met and the page is refreshed, Do Something repeats.

Answer (score 0):

If the data source is a table or TableSet, I have a function I've written that calculates a checksum against the current column values, and I store that before editing.   When it comes time to save, I calculate the checksum against the new row data, and if it's changed, I know I need to post the data.

For objects that get data-bound to a grid, I have a private "dirty" flag that I set whenever an editable property changes:  before editing I clear that flag, and afterwards check it.

My property setters all look something like this:

```
private string _name = "";
private bool _dirty = false;
...

string Name
{
     get { return _name; }

     set { if (value != _name)
           {
              _dirty = true;
              _name = value;
           }
         }
}
```

Comment: Hi Curt, thanks for taking a look. One question, how is this better than what I did? Since mine is working, what would be the advantage.

Comment: @DougFarrell  Efficiency.   In most of my projects, I mainly want to know if a value has been changed before I decide to apply new validation, cleansing, and (perhaps) posting to the record.   By constraining the comparison to a single protected/internal variable, I don't have to engage in long `if ((oldA != newA)  ||  (oldB != newB) || (oldC != newC))...` calculation to see if I need to take specific action.    I have abstracted the logic in the setter I showed to a single generic function, so the actual implementation is quite simple, too.